# Android fill listview header

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I am building an news application. I want to display news in a ListView with data from a url. But I need to skip first row, instead of putting data in first row to display a ListView header. This is inflated with different layout, but I cannot modify this adapter class. Can anyone help me?

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        if(position==0){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_main, null);
        }else{
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView big_img = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.einfo3); // artist name
        TextView author = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.einfo1); // duration
        TextView datetimev = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tVdatetime);
        TextView story = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.einfo2);
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> n = new HashMap<String, String>();
        n = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(n.get(Home.TAG_TITLE));
        author.setText(n.get(Home.TAG_AUTHOR));
        datetimev.setText(n.get(Home.TAG_DATETIME));
        story.setText(n.get(Home.TAG_STORY));
        thumb_image.setTag(n.get(Home.TAG_BIG_IMG));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(n.get(Home.TAG_BIG_IMG), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [ListView.addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29).

```
listView.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row_main, null));
```